# How to catch Mailchimp validation error (mce-inline-error)

Tags: mailchimp

this is my email form

```
<form action="https://gmail.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=XXXXXX" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;">
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            <span id="mce-EMAIL-HELPERTEXT" class="helper_text"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_fb16c0b54b243c41cf0ba431c_6cbe3da72c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="optionalParent">
            <div class="clear foot">
                <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="rehab-btn-secondary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

however if I input "aaa" as email address which is wrong. I am getting this error
[image]

Which obviosly breaks our UI,
by checking on the HTML in dev tools, it creates a new div with id "mce-inline-error"
out of the blue, how can i control this error so i can style it properly in our UI?
[image]

This is getting annoying google cant give me answer.

If there are no answers, what type of work around can you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

this is a code on client side, executed by the js mailchimp.
you can manually import the mailchimp js and update the messages content